# Camel route to delete old files

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement to delete files which do not get a .done file within 24 hours of the time that they drop.  Is there a way to do this with Camel, Spring Xml, so that I can keep all of this processing in one bundle?  So, I would need to find a file with no matching .done file, and where CamelFileLastModified is 24 hours earlier than the current time.  Finding the file with no matching .done file is my concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom file filter, where you check for whether a .done file exists or not. And also do the age check.

The custom filter is just java code so you can write a little bit of code to see if file with .done exists or not. And as well check that header if the age is > 24h

There is a `filter` option you can use: http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: Right, I had seen that, but what I haven't seen is a way to implement the filter without writing any java code.  My client's use of Camel is based on the idea that none of us .net developers will need to write java code.  If there's no way to do this, then we'll need to discuss which route we want to take (pun intended).

Comment: Are .Net developers not able to write code? Writing 5-10 lines of Java code is not scary and something a modest developers should be able to learn and do.

Comment: If you only want XML then you could try using groovy, you can even inlined that into the xml - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html

Comment: Sorry, but your first comment is entirely unhelpful and smacks of ism.  My general policy is to never vote down a comment or even answer and I'll stick to that here.  Yes, I know who you are, which is why it's even more disappointing that you'd go for a cheap comment. The point is that my client, who pays the bills, wants to stay away from maintaining both java and .net.  They believe that Camel could fill a specific weakness of .Net.  In spite of your attitude, I'm trying to make it work for them. You might've started and stopped with suggesting groovy.

Comment: you can only do as much without any kind of coding, and when you need to then you must code a bit whether its Java / Groovy / JavaScript etc but a programming language on the JVM. Some simpler tasks can be done in just XML configuration, but you will eventually need to code. Hence if you must not code, then maybe look elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I have suspected as much but the client has a number of bundles defined with Xml and no Java.  Ironically, they also have a number that are all java, but they're trying to move away from this.  I personally only care about results, and, writing the java we're talking about is easier than helping my son with his high school programming class in java.  But, I don't get to make the decision. Ironically, a solution that was made was to do this with SCOM, but I'd prefer the java code which would remain obvious to anyone looking at the bundle later.

Comment: Yeah any new hire developer should be able to maintain and understand some basic java code, that does a simple file exists check and if the file age is > X hours. If Camel had some support for this combination you would likely end up in a programming like language that is not standard and new hires and others would need to learn. The power with Camel is the opposite. Its just Java / Groovy / etc.